# Using PIConnect in Docker Container

Tags: docker, osisoft

I am trying to contenerize my code which comprises PIConnect library. Below is my dockerfile.

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.11
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base

RUN pip install piaf
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mono-complete

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser


RUN pip install PIConnect

RUN pip install pythonnet
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIAF_SDK:$PWD

USER appuser

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

RUN mono --version

CMD ["python", "main.py", "--data_dir2", "/container/path2"]
```

After the container is succesfully build, when I try to run it,
I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/clr_loader/mono.py:180: UserWarning: Hosting Mono versions before v6.12 is known to be problematic. If the process crashes shortly after you see this message, try updating Mono to at least v6.12.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    import PIconnect as PI
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIconnect/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PIconnect.AFSDK import AF, AF_SDK_VERSION
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIconnect/AFSDK.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise ImportError("PIAF SDK not found, check installation")
ImportError: PIAF SDK not found, check installation
```

Can someone please let me know whats the issue. Is it even possible to encorporate PIConnect sdk inside a container.